# Is the word "to me" omitted after "over"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In *F9 (2021)*, through Dom, Jakob finds key exist in Elle's DNA:

> Jakob: I've been looking for that key for a long time, Dom. And you
> just **handed her over**.

Is the word "to me" omitted after "over"? Does it mean Dom handed Elle's DNA to Jakob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "to me" are omitted from that sentence.

However, that is probably not the question you wish to ask, the question you probably wish to ask is, "Are the words 'to me' omitted accidentally or deliberately?"

I suspect they are omitted from the dialogue deliberately. Jakob says he has wanted to find the key for a long time. The very short except you give makes it appear that Jakob is complaining that the key was handed over. Ideally, people would complain only when they don't get what they want, not when they get what they ask for.

If the words "to me" were omitted by mistake, a simple version of the dialogue might be like this:

> Jakob: I wanted the key for so long. You handed it over **to me**. *Now I am complaining to you that I got what I wanted.*

That just doesn't make sense.

The actual dialogue implies Dom handed the key to someone other than Jakob and Jakob is disappointed because Dom could have easily given the key to Jakob, ending Jakob's search.

Comment: is it right!!!!? After thinking it over, give your opinions. The presented sentence is that "you just handed her over.". If "to me" is omitted, the complete sentence is following. "you just handed her over to me." Does it make a sense?